# Building a Flutter Web App with --source-map has no effect

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to export the sourcemap for my application but after running

`fvm flutter build web --source-maps -t lib/main_live.dart`

the sourcemaps are not in the expected \web directory. How can I get the sourcemap?